# how to read the controller ModelAndView setObject in Javascript in Spring Boot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a controller which has set some values and I am returning the ModelAndView Object. Now I am able to access this object in the Thyme-leaf but unable to access in the javascript file. Any suggestions?

I tried using
 [CDATA[/ ... var username = /*[[${session.user.name}]]*/ 'Sebastian'; ... /]]>

It worked perfectly when I am writing the script in thymeleaf page itself but it doesn't work when I am creating the separate JavaScript file and writing the same code

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried all the suggested post which i searched on google like modelAndView.addObject("journal","journal123"); I can access in javascript using following code var message = "${journal}"; but it is not working. Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried using /*<![CDATA[*/
    ...

    var username = /*[[${session.user.name}]]*/ 'Sebastian';

    ...
/*]]>*/ It worked perfectly when I am writing the script in thymeleaf page itself but it doesn't work when I am creating the separate JavaScript file and writing the same code.

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
   /*<![CDATA[*/

     var test = /*[[${journal}]]*/ 'test';

   /*]]>*/
   alert(test);
}); this is the code which i wrote but not working

Comment: Can you post it in your original question as edit?